# will all those "closed as offtopic" questions be migrated automatically to softwarerecs?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons, off-topic, software-recs-se

I recently noticed that there is softwarerecs.stackexchange.com (in beta)
Will those questions asked across all SE sites and closed as offtopic because they were asking for software recommendations be automatically migrated to the new dedicated site when it will exit the beta?

Comment: Do you think they're all good examples?

Comment: @random if the're not, then the moderators have wrongly categorized them as "software recommendations", in which case you will have to question the moderators' ability to be a moderator.

Comment: @CostinGușă I believe you may be using the term moderator wrong - are you referring to diamond-moderators or users who have the ability to close questions?  There are community members with privileges to help moderate the site, so whose ability are you questioning?

Comment: this is an example closed as offtopic because of software recommendation. is it eligible to be moved to softwarerecs? the "moderators" that I am referring to are the names who voted to be closed. https://serverfault.com/questions/577996/logcheck-alternative-for-central-syslog-server

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A few things to consider here:

- Posts older than 60 days are not generally migrated (needs SE staff for that to happen).
- First rule of migrations - don't migrate low quality posts.
- In order to automatically migrate such questions, there needs to be a way to automatically identify them. There isn't such a way.
- Not all software recommendation requests are of high quality. Identifying the high quality ones is not an easy task, especially not automatically.

Given all the above, it is very unlikely to see many migrations to the site, automatic or otherwise.

Comment: Also: Migrating questions to a beta site is rarely a good idea. There's very little benefit - if any - for a young community from a flood of old, answered and heavily upvoted (for beta standards) questions.

Comment: @Yannis - that was my initial point, which I removed (during the grace period), after noticing that OP is asking for this once the site graduates (in their words "when it will exit the beta").

Comment: Ah, I completely missed that.